# How to assign a value to a dataframe column for rows where another column contains that value?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python and I was wondering if someone could help me.
My code as below is not working as I need:

```
#----- Importing the libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#----- Data
testing = {
    'Details': ['Green Mercedes', 'Blue mercedes', 'Green ford', 'Red ford', 'Blue Kia', 'Green Audi'],
    'Color': ['','','','','',''],
}

#----- creating a Dataframe object
df = pd.DataFrame(testing)
color1 = "Green"

#----- Applying the condition
if 'Green' in df['Details']:
    df['color'] = df['color'].apply.color1

print(df)
```

output:

```
         Details Color
0  Green Mercedes
1   Blue mercedes
2      Green ford
3        Red ford
4        Blue Kia
5      Green Audi
```

I need to update "Color" depending on part of the information in "details" but this script is not doing it. Could someone please help me?

Update:
My question now is if I need two conditions how would I do below?

```
#----- Importing the libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#----- Data
testing = {
    'Details': ['Green Mercedes', 'Blue mercedes', 'Green ford', 'Red ford', 'Blue Kia', 'Green Audi'],
    'Sold': ['Yes','Yes','No','No','Yes','No'],
    'Color': ['','','','','',''],
}

#----- creating a Dataframe object
df = pd.DataFrame(testing)
color1 = "Green Sold"
color2 = "Green not sold"

#----- Applying the condition
df['Color'] = df['Color'].mask(df['Details'].str.contains('Green'), color1)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please tell me how would I do if I need two conditions? I have updated my question?

Comment: My answer edited to cover multiple conditions. You might have to first use `import numpy as np` if this is not already part of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have gone awry both on how to access columns in pandas and how apply is used. The mask() function uses a condition and a value to use if the condition is True' Also note the use of `.str.contains` to check for a substring in a column value.

Use:

```
df['Color'] = df['Color'].mask(df['Details'].str.contains('Green'), color1)
```

which gives

```
          Details  Color
0  Green Mercedes  Green
1   Blue mercedes       
2      Green ford  Green
3        Red ford       
4        Blue Kia       
5      Green Audi  Green
```

For 2 or more conditions you could obviously repeat the statement with different values. But a more efficient approach is to use numpy `select` as follows:

```
cond1 = df['Details'].str.contains('Green')
cond2 = df['Details'].str.contains('Red')
default = '' # use any default value or df['Color'] to keep original value
df['Color'] = np.select([cond1, cond2], ['Green', 'Red'], default)
```

which gives:

```
          Details  Color
0  Green Mercedes  Green
1   Blue mercedes       
2      Green ford  Green
3        Red ford    Red
4        Blue Kia       
5      Green Audi  Green
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to find the rows that contain the substring `'Green'`:

```
mask = df['Details'].str.contains(color1)
```

This gives the following `mask`, where the value is `True` when the `df['Details']` column contains the substring `'Green'`, and `False` elsewhere.

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: Details, dtype: bool
```

Then, you want to assign the value of `color1` to rows for which that `mask` is `True`:

```
df.loc[mask, 'Color'] = color1
```

This leaves you with the following `df`:

```
          Details  Color
0  Green Mercedes  Green
1   Blue mercedes       
2      Green ford  Green
3        Red ford       
4        Blue Kia       
5      Green Audi  Green
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you want to achieve you do not need multiple ifs or masks. If you simply want the Color column to contain the colour you can do:

```py
#----- Importing the libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#----- Data
testing = {
    'Details': ['Green Mercedes', 'Blue mercedes', 'Green ford', 'Red ford', 'Blue Kia', 'Green Audi'],
    'Color': ['','','','','',''],
}

# no need to use ifs and masks
df.Color = df.Details.str.split(" ").str[0]
df

# output:
    Details Color
0   Green Mercedes  Green
1   Blue mercedes   Blue
2   Green ford  Green
3   Red ford    Red
4   Blue Kia    Blue
5   Green Audi  Green
```